# A man on a high gravity planet becomes more alien with exposure to planet and starts to understand aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, communication

That's about all I remember.  I was really impressed with the way the author portrayed the changes in the man and the alien communication.  I think the man was on a science base which got damaged.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for writing good story-id questions to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Can you describe any of the changes that the main character undergoes?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a stretch, but you could be thinking of The Space Trilogy by C S Lewis.

> The Space Trilogy or Cosmic Trilogy is a series of science fiction
>   novels by C. S. Lewis, famous for his later series The Chronicles of
>   Narnia. A philologist named Elwin Ransom is the hero of the first two
>   novels and an important character in the third.

Sources from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Trilogy

> Out of the Silent Planet (1938), set mostly on Mars (Malacandra). In
>   this book, Elwin Ransom voyages to Mars and discovers that Earth is
>   exiled from the rest of the Solar System. Far back in Earth's past, it
>   fell to an angelic being known as the Bent Oyarsa, and now, to prevent
>   contamination of the rest of the Solar System ("The Field of Arbol"),
>   it is known as "the silent planet" (Thulcandra).

Old Solar Language:

> According to the Space Trilogy's cosmology, the speech of all the
>   inhabitants of the Field of Arbol is the Old Solar or
>   Hlab-Eribol-ef-Cordi. Only Earth lost the language, due to the Bent
>   One's influence. Old Solar can be likened to the Elvish languages
>   invented by Lewis's friend, Tolkien. The grammar is little known,
>   except for the plurals of nouns. The plurals of some words (hross,
>   eldil) are simple, only adding a final -a or -i; others (as for
>   Oyarsa, sorn, hnakra), are quite complex broken plurals, adding an
>   internal -é-, and adding or altering a final vowel (usually to -i or
>   -u), and may also include internal metathesis (Oyéresu, séroni, hnéraki).

Comment: The planet he's on in the first book is Mars, which isn't even high gravity